# cannot find symbol WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, spring-security

Estoy haciendo practicando con JWT con spring boot, pero cuando quiero importar WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter nose que pasa que aparece tachada y cuando quiero compilar no me dice que el error es puntualmente la importacion pero si me dice que el error viene de esta clase, donde es lo unico sospechoso que veo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Lei que puede ser una mala importacion en el archivo pom pero descargando cualquier version de spring-security-started ni config pude solucionar

Comment: [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) está deprecada. Revisa [este artículo](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) del equipo de spring security para configurar tu proyecto sin utilizar esta clase.

Answer (score 2):

Esto se debe al cambio reciente en la versión Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 sobre como editar la configuración de spring security.

Intenta bajar la versión de spring a la 2.6.10 en el archivo pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

O puedes usar el modo de configuración para las nuevas versiones de la siguiente forma.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Puuedes seguir la siguiente guía para migrar el código a la nueva versión también.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter